# Unable to boot Ubuntu as boot menu disappeared in Windows 10. Now have Windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside with Windows 10 in dual boot. For a few months, I was able to access Ubuntu from the boot menu. But suddenly boot menu didn't load and Windows 10 directly loaded. Recently I upgraded Windows 10 to Windows 11. Do I still have a chance to access Ubuntu and how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi. Search for "YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS" in the first answer.

Comment: Windows updates often turn its fast startup/hibernation back on. You may need to just turn it off again. Also updates may update UEFI, which often resets UEFI to defaults. You may need to review the settings you originally changed to install Ubuntu. Details in heynnema link.